# Issue with rviz:Markers Sending Basic Shapes (C++). Running "rosrun using_markers basic_shapes": "Please create a subscriber to the marker"

Tags: ros, c++, rviz, markers, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1.my rosdistro: indigo; my ros workspace is catkin.

2.my tutorial:[link text](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes)
3.and then when i run :rosrun rviz rviz, it come up with nothing in my rviz, like this picture:no fixed frame, no shape on the plane.

---

- List item

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267860/when-i-study-the-rviz:markers:-sending-basic-shapes-(c++),-i-come-across-some-problem:-when-i-run-this-order:-rosrun-using_markers-basic_shapes,-it-told-me-that-%22please-create-a-subscriber-to-the-marker%22,so-how-to-solve-this-problem?/) by [liangminglan55](https://answers.ros.org/users/31415/liangminglan55/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This problem is solved by doing exactly what it told you: "Please create a subscriber to the marker"

When you do `rosrun using_markers basic_shapes`, this node publishes to topic `/visualization_markers`. You can verify that markers are being published by running `rostopic echo /visualisation_markers` in another terminal.

To visualise the marker in rviz, you have to do few additional things in rviz:

1. Add display of `Marker` (this subscribes to the marker topic)
2. Change the Fixed frame to `my_frame` (this is specified in line 47 of basic_shapes node)

[gif illustrating above points](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1jURzlre6cAV2lvdmpJRFZWUmM/view?usp=sharing)

---

Originally posted by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) with karma: 161 on 2017-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0